Is there a way to make paho.mqtt.cpp use the windows trusted root certificate authorities
If I push the ca to clients using a gpo then I would like paho.mqtt.cpp client library to check against the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities on the windows boxes.
Chrome, Edge and cpprestsdk websockets works fine with my self signed certificate setup, last challenge is the paho mqtt cpp part..
I was hoping for a .set_trust_store("WINDOWS"); or similar.
Code showing the regular loading of the cert that is hand carried to the clients.
if(true)
{
    mqtt::ssl_options sslOpts;
    sslOpts.set_verify(true);
    sslOpts.set_ssl_version(3);
    
     std::string cacrt = "c:\\cert\\selfsigned.crt");//works fine by must be placed manually on client pcs
    sslOpts.ca_path(cacrt);
    sslOpts.set_trust_store(cacrt); 
    connOpts.set_ssl(sslOpts);
}

The paco.mqtt.c library has a "disableDefaultTrustStore" in the MQTTClient_SSLOptions struct, I am hoping for something similar in the cpp version.
Is there a way to reliably load a cert from the Local Computer certificates and use it as the ca, or even better make paho validate againt this store?

The paho client uses openssl under the hood, which should be able to use the Windows store, but it may needs mods to the client to tell it to use it. The CPP library is just a wrapper on the c client
